# Find the number of pairs in an array with product between l and r incluseive

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search, array-algorithms

[**this is the actual question**](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/primality-tests/practice-problems/algorithm/nakul-and-gold-coins/)

however, it simplifies to

Find all **SEMPIPRIMES** (numbers which are products of 2 DISTINCT prime factors e.g. 6 (2*3) in range L to R

there will be multiple queries for L and R

**we cant precompute semiprimes as N is large**

BUT we can store primes as they are only upto **10^6 as per the question**

Now, assume i have all primes by **sieve of eratostheneses**

i need all possible pairs of primes with product between L to R

**OR THE QUESTION SIMPLIFIES TO GIVEN A SORTED ARRAY. 
FIND ALL POSSIBLE PAIRS WITH PRODUCTS BETWEEN L AND R INCLUSIVE**

i am including the part of code in the editorial which does this..

```
for(int i=0; i<cnt and ar[i]<=r; i++)
{
    int lower = L/ar[i];
    if(L%ar[i]>0)
        lower++;
    lower = max(lower, ar[i]+1);
    int upper = R/ar[i];
    if(upper<lower)
        continue;
    ans += upper_bound(ar.begin(),ar.end(),upper)-
            lower_bound(ar.begin(),ar.end(),lower);
}
```

Comment: post the code you have tried so far

Comment: Is the test case right? I mean, 8 have 4 distinct factors : 1, 2, 4, 8. Why isn't it counted?

Comment: @Daniel question says "Note2 Any 3 sides taken together will be mutually co-prime."

Comment: @komatiraju032 here is the link to my code -> https://ideone.com/gDVHWB but as i said it wont work as i was precomputing primes and n is upto 10^8 so i was getting runtime error for only the last 2 cases

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, this may not be faster but it seems reasonable.

1. The number of primes below 10^8 is around 5*10^6.

reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

2. But we may not have to keep all the primes, as it would be rather inefficient. We can keep the Semiprimes only.

There's already the generative process for Semprimes. Each Semiprime is a product of 2 distinct prime factors.

So, we can keep an array which will store all the semiprimes, as there will be at most 10^5 semiprimes in the range, we can sort that array. For each query, we will just binary search on the array to find the number of elements in the range.

3. So, how to save the semiprimes?

We can slightly modify the sieve of Eratosthenes to generate semiprimes.

The idea is we will keep a `countDivision` array which will store the number of divisor for each integer in range. We only consider a integer semiprime is `countDivision` index value is 2 for that integer (2 divisors).

```
def createSemiPrimeSieve(n): 
    v = [0 for i in range(n + 1)] 

    # This array will initially store the indexes 
    # After performing below operations if any 
    # element of array becomes 1 this means 
    # that the given index is a semi-prime number 

    # Storing indices in each element of vector 
    for i in range(1, n + 1): 
        v[i] = i 

    countDivision = [0 for i in range(n + 1)] 

    for i in range(n + 1): 
        countDivision[i] = 2

    # This array will initially be initialized by 2 and 
    # will just count the divisions of a number 
    # As a semiprime number has only 2 prime factors 
    # which means after dividing by the 2 prime numbers 
    # if the index countDivision[x] = 0 and v[x] = 1 
    # this means that x is a semiprime number 

    # If number a is prime then its 
    # countDivision[a] = 2 and v[a] = a 

    for i in range(2, n + 1, 1): 

        # If v[i] != i this means that it is 
        # not a prime number as it contains 
        # a divisor which has already divided it 
        # same reason if countDivision[i] != 2 
        if (v[i] == i and countDivision[i] == 2): 

            # j goes for each factor of i 
            for j in range(2 * i, n + 1, i): 
                if (countDivision[j] > 0): 

                    # Dividing the number by i 
                    # and storing the dividend 
                    v[j] = int(v[j] / i) 

                    # Decreasing the countDivision 
                    countDivision[j] -= 1

    # A new vector to store all Semi Primes 
    res = [] 

    for i in range(2, n + 1, 1): 

        # If a number becomes one and 
        # its countDivision becomes 0 
        # it means the number has 
        # two prime divisors 
        if (v[i] == 1 and countDivision[i] == 0): 
            res.append(i) 

    return res
```

Credit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-semi-prime-numbers-less-than-or-equal-to-n/

But, generating has same complexity as sieve which is `O(nloglogn)`. If (R-L) is < 10^5 this approach will pass. But as (R-L) can be as big as 10^8 it's not feasible.

Another approach is to ***count*** instead of generating.

Let's work on an example.

`2 10`

Now, let's say, we know all the primes up to 10^6 (as `p` and `q` can't be more than 10^6).

`primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...]`

> The number of primes below 10^6 is less than 10^5 (so we can store
>   them in an array) and the time complexity is also manageable.

Now, we can scan our `primes` array to count the contribution for each prime to generate semiprimes in range (L, R).

First, let's start with 2, how many semiprimes we'll generate with the help of 2.

Let's look at primes = `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ..]`

We can't choose 2, because 2 and 2 are not different (p, q must be different). But, 3 is in, as 2*3 <= 10, so is 5, 2*5 2*5 <= 10.

How to count this?

We will take the lower bound as 2//2 `(L//primes[i])` but we have to make sure, we don't consider the current prime again as (p and q must be different) so we take the max of `L//primes[i]` and `primes[i]+1`.

For 2, our start number is 3 (because of 2+1 = 3, we can't start at 1 or 2 as if we consider 2 then we'll calculate cases like 2*2 = 4 which is not valid). Our end number is 10//2 = 5, how many numbers are there within range 3, 5 in primes. It's 2 and can be found via a simple binary search.

Rest is easy, we'll have to binary search how many primes are there in range `(max(L//primes[i], primes[i]+1), R//primes[i])`.

This has complexity pre-processing time complexity of O(10^6*loglog(10^6)) + O(10^6*log(10^6)) and O(log(10^6)) per query.